# What to use instead of QTCaptureDevice?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I notice that in the documentation for QTCaptureDevice (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/quicktime/reference/QTCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it seems like it is being depreciated?

What are you supposed to use instead for doing screen / audio recordings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the QTKit is phased out and you are encouraged to use AVFoundation. It offers similiar functionality and much more

in this case use a AVCaptureDevice to make a AVCaptureSession

e.g. set up a camera view

```
AVCaptureDevice * captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput * captureDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:error];

AVCaptureSession * captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];    
[captureSession beginConfiguration];
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
[captureSession addInput:captureDeviceInput];
AVCaptureStillImageOutput * output = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
[captureSession addOutput:output];

[captureSession commitConfiguration];    
[captureSession startRunning];
```

Comment: there is a lot of apple provided sample code for this

Comment: the above code is NOT production code -- it omits all the recommended error checking. It is only meant to serve as a pointer

Comment: This is great, thanks. I wasn't sure that was the replacement!